# Ruby .to_i does not return the complete integer as expected

Tags: ruby

My ruby command is,

```
"980,323,344.00".to_i
```

Why does it return 980 instead of 980323344?

Comment: if you check https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i, you'll see that *Ruby* will convert it until the first non number character is found in your case.

Comment: You would need to remove the commas or substitute them with underscores. e.g. `'980,323,344.00'.tr(',','').to_i #=> 980323344` or `'980,323,344.00'.tr(',','_').to_i #=> 980323344`

Comment: are you getting that "number" from a source you don't control ?, if so, you could try `"980,323,344.00".gsub(",", "_").to_i`

Comment: `"12monkeys".to_i` is also `12`, just as `"se7en".to_i` is `0`.

Comment: It would help if you could explain what, *precisely*, is unclear to you about the documentation of `String#to_i`. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't stumble over the same rocks you did.

Comment: @engineersmnky, weird but true: `'980,323,344.00'.tr(',','_').to_i`.

Comment: `delete(',')` will now remove '.' so prefer `to_f` if you do not want loss. Perhaps if you intend integer then it's ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing this :

```
"980,323,344.00".delete(',').to_i
```

The reason your method call to `to_i` does not return as expected is explained [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i), and to quote, the method :

> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an integer base base (between 2 and 36). **Extraneous characters** past the end of a valid number are ignored.

Extraneous characters in your case would be the comma character that ends at `980`, the reason why you see `980` being returned

Answer (score 3):

In ruby calling `to_i` on a string will truncate from the beginning of  a string where possible.

```
number_string = '980,323,344.00'
number_string.delete(',').to_i
#=> 980323344

"123abc".to_i
#=> 123
```

If you want to add underscores to make longer number more readable, those can be used where the conventional commas would be in written numbers.

```
"980_323_344.00".to_i
#=> 980323344
```

Comment: Safer to just get rid of them.

Comment: @tadman but far less readable if you need the `String` for some reason

Comment: @engineersmnky I mean get rid of them when processing as done here in the second example as opposed to remapping them as in the first.

Comment: That's even better. Nice.

Comment: The OP may be given `"980,323,344.00"` or may express it that way for reasons unrelated to the question, so I don't think you should suggest that underscores be used instead of commas. The point is that `to_i` can be used if the string contains any number and placement of underscores, provided there are not two underscores in a row and the string does not begin with one. Similar rules apply to integers and floats. This is done merely to make literals more readable. However,...

Comment: ...all this is secondary to the question of how an integer or a  float is to be extracted from a string containing commas that is the representation of a number. You've answered that, but only in part 2 of your answer. I suggest your make that front and centre and then explain--almost as an aside-- why underscores might be used in literals.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/String.html#method-i-to_i) might be a bit misleading:

> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in *str* as an integer base *base* (between 2 and 36)

*"interpreting"* doesn't mean that it tries to parse various number formats (like `Date.parse` does for date formats). It means that it looks for what's a valid [integer literal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers) in Ruby (in the given base). For example:

```
 1234.            #=> 1234
'1234'.to_i       #=> 1234

 1_234.           #=> 1234
'1_234'.to_i.     #=> 1234

 0d1234           #=> 1234
'0d1234'.to_i     #=> 1234

 0x04D2           #=> 1234
'0x04D2'.to_i(16) #=> 1234
```

Your input as a whole however is not a valid integer literal: (Ruby doesn't like the `,`)

```
980,323,344.00
# SyntaxError (syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input)
# 980,323,344.00
#    ^
```

But it *starts* with a valid integer literal. And that's where the the seconds sentence comes into play:

> Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored.

So the result is `980` – the leading characters which form a valid integer converted to an integer.

---

If your strings always have that format, you can just [`delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/String.html#method-i-delete) the offending commas and run the result through `to_i` which will ignore the trailing `.00`:

```
'980,323,344.00'.delete(',')      #=> "980323344.00"
'980,323,344.00'.delete(',').to_i #=> 980323344
```

Otherwise you could use a regular expression to check its format before converting it:

```
input = '980,323,344.00'
number = case input
         when /\A\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.00\z/
           input.delete(',').to_i
         when /other format/
           # other conversion
         end
```

And if you are dealing with monetary values, you should consider using the [money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem and its [monetize](https://github.com/RubyMoney/monetize/) addition for parsing formatted values:

```
 amount = Monetize.parse('980,323,344.00')
 #=> #<Money fractional:98032334400 currency:USD>

 amount.format
 #=> "$980.323.344,00"
```

Note that `format` requires [i18n](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n) so the above example might require some setup.